# Problem downloading large files on password protected site using Java

Tags: java, security

I have been able to connect to and download files such as text and images from a password protected site by using a java's password authenticator class and overriding it. However now I'm having an issue downloading zip files from the same site. 
I think it may be size related since the zips are about 3 MBs while the images are about 30KBs in size. Since I can download these via my web browser it should be using the same username and password so that shouldn't be an issue. Without the login and password the zips downloaded fine so I don't think it has to do with my downloading code.

My theory is there is some kind of authentication time out or something related to larger files, or after downloading a certain amount of information there is some kind of requery. However this is the first time I've dealt with this issue so I have no idea what exactly the problem is or how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the relevant code:

```
  private class mAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
  private int numtries = 0;
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
        String promptString = getRequestingPrompt();
        String hostname = getRequestingHost();
         InetAddress ipaddr = getRequestingSite();
         int port = getRequestingPort();
         String username = "foo";
         String password = "bar";
         return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
  }
 }



public String DownloadFile(String url, String placetostore, String filename){
String mString = null;
URL myURL = 
new URL(url); 
URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = 
new BufferedInputStream(is); 
ByteArrayBuffer baf = 
new ByteArrayBuffer(50); 
int current = 0; 
while((current = bis.read()) != -1){ 
baf.append((
byte)current); 
}
String fileloc = placetostore + filename;
File file = 
new File(fileloc); 
FileOutputStream fos = 
new FileOutputStream(file); 
fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
fos.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) { 
// TODO Auto-generated catch block 
e.printStackTrace();
}
return mString; 
}
```

Comment: You should give a snippet of the code you are using to download from Java

Comment: I've added the code I used to authenticate as well as download.

Answer (score 1):

> My theory is there is some kind of authentication time out or something related to larger files ...

It won't be an *authentication* timeout.  Unless the server-side is implemented in a most peculiar way, authentication is checked before the server starts delivering the response to your GET request ... and then not again.

But there could be a simple timeout on the delivery of the file.  If your client takes too long reading the file, the server could just close the stream.  (This kind of thing might be done to conserve server-side resources, protect against accidental or deliberate DoS attacks, etc).

The difference in behaviour between user/password versus not could be down to using TLS, and the server being configured with different timeouts for different message transports.

> ... or after downloading a certain amount of information there is some kind of requery.

That is not possible.  The file is delivered in a single HTTP response message, and HTTP has no provision for reauthenticating halfway through a response.

---

It would be a good idea if you posted the client-side download code so that we can see if you are doing something suboptimal.